# npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME in installing a package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-install

i am trying to install a package in my react app
but i get this error

```
$ npm install xlsx
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "react-scripts  start": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.
```

this is my scripts in  package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

version of react is 17
and my node version is 17
but app created by a different version of node

i don't know what to do

Comment: Try this ,
npm  install --save https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-0.18.7/xlsx-0.18.7.tgz

Comment: no, different error

Answer (score 1):

it was becuase the version of my npm
i downgrade it and problem solved

```
npm install -g npm@6.14.14
```